# What image scaling/interpolation algorithm does OS X use?

Tags: macos, graphics, scaling

All of Apple's software uses a distinctive image scaling algorithm built into the OS. Both OS X and iOS use it. It might seem like a silly question, but does anybody know what it's called and/or how it works? It doesn't look like simple bicubic/bilinear

Comment: Are you talking about how `UIImage`s are drawn when their scale property is changed? Or actual (destructive) rescaling operations?